# How to reduce size for Angular JS app where vendor.js is 2MB and app.js is 720KB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, minify, uglifyjs

I am working on an AngularJS web application. I used uglify and minify to create vendor.js and app.js files but they are incredibly huge - 2 MB and 720KB respectively. As I see in Chrome Dev tools, they took 25s and 14s respectively to download which I think is a lot of time on my 100MBPS internet connection. I am worried about customer experience who might have far less speed than this. What are ways to compress or reduce the size of these files ? I believe vendor.js cannot be broken down because Angular needs all of it on the first page.

Comment: Look through the modules you are using to see where the bulk is coming from, there are likely some modules that are doing way more than you need them to do that you can do away with.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest and quickest wins will be serving the files with gzip compression and on a CDN(cloudfront, akamai, etc). The CDN will usually serve the files from a location that is physically closer to the user(quicker to download). Most CDN's make it easy to enable gzip and that is probably where you will get your biggest win on file size.

After that you could look at tree-shaking. This may require a lot of refactoring if you aren't already using something to bundle your javascript like webpack. But the nice thing with tree-shaking is that it will exclude any code that you aren't using from your app.js and vendor.js files.

And finally you could look at lazy loading. This way you bootstrap your app with the minimum amount of code needed and as the user navigates to different parts of the app they download what they need. ocLazyLoad tends to be the popular choice if you are on 1.x: https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: OP has already stated that they used uglify, which implies that tree-shaking has more or less been applied. UglifyJs default compression settings will drop dead and unused code: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress